# ordinal suffix of the letter of a word python 3.5.

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
import string
import sys

vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
consonants = [x for x in string.ascii_lowercase if x not in vowels]
SelectedWords = ['TRAILER', 'LAPTOP', 'SUNFLOWER', 'SKIPPING', 'AIRPLANE', 'HOUR', 'POTATO', 'HUGE', 'TINY', 'GOOD', 'BAD', 'YES', 'NO', 'WAGON', 'QUESTION', 'LAGOON', 'CAT', 'DUCK', 'GOANNA', 'POSTER', 'FUTURE', 'PRINCESS', 'RHYTHM', 'SUDDENLY', 'SNOW', 'MAGNET', 'TOWEL', 'RUNNING', 'SPEAKER', 'QUICKLY']
word_map = {x:{'consonants':len([y for y in x.lower() if y in consonants]), 'vowels':len([y for y in x.lower() if y in vowels]), 'letters':len(x)} for x in SelectedWords}
```

the below is part of a loop that creates random questions from 4 choices and then assigns a word to those questions.

For this question when the program might get a results of what is the letter 5 of hospital, the user would then input a answer and then get a correct or incorrect response. What I'm trying to do is  get the ordinal suffix of  the letter as well . So the question could be "what is the 5th letter of hospital"

```
        n = random.randint(1, len(x))
        correct = x[n-1]
        if sys.version.startswith('3'):
            ans = str(input('What is letter {} of "{}"?'.format(n, x)))
        else:
            ans = str(raw_input('What is letter {} of "{}"?'.format(n, x)))
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but are you looking to turn "5" into "5th"?

Comment: yep that is correct I'm just trying to get the wording better so instead of what what is letter 5 of gorilla is will pull up the ordinal suffix so it can be what the is 5th letter of gorilla?

Comment: For future reference when you ask a question on SO, ask the specific question you want answered.  Provide your attempt at solving that problem and nothing else unless additional information is requested.  You are likely to get better / faster answers that way.

Comment: @sberry I don't feel you really reinforced that by then writing the OP's code for them

Comment: @jonrsharpe I understand your point, but I mostly try to avoid the "How do I do this" without showing any code at all.  At least in the OP's situation they have demonstrated that they indeed have written something so it isn't as if they have zero clue.  Still, fair point.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to convert 1 => 1st, 2 => 2nd, 3 => 3rd, etc... this is the easiest way I can think of.  This special cases 1, 2, 3 and all numbers ending in 1, 2 or 3 except 11, 12 and 13.

```
num_suffix = lambda x: "{}{}".format(x, {1: "st", 2: "nd", 3: "rd"}.get(0 if 10 > x > 14 else x % 10, "th"))

for i in range(1, 40):
    print("{} => {}".format(i, num_suffix(i))

1 => 1st
2 => 2nd
3 => 3rd
4 => 4th
5 => 5th
6 => 6th
7 => 7th
8 => 8th
9 => 9th
10 => 10th
11 => 11th
12 => 12th
13 => 13th
14 => 14th
15 => 15th
16 => 16th
17 => 17th
18 => 18th
19 => 19th
20 => 20th
21 => 21st
22 => 22nd
23 => 23rd
24 => 24th
25 => 25th
26 => 26th
27 => 27th
28 => 28th
29 => 29th
30 => 30th
31 => 31st
32 => 32nd
33 => 33rd
34 => 34th
35 => 35th
36 => 36th
37 => 37th
38 => 38th
39 => 39th
```

And I think 0 is actually 0th, but not sure.  You could special case that as well.

Comment: What is the 21st letter of Floccinaucinihilipilification?

Comment: @JamesK Unfortunately I have shoes on so I can only currently count to 10.

Comment: @JamesK, indeed, I see now - doh!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full revised code. There will obviously be issues with numbers larger than 10, it would be possible to either add numbers to the map or write a function with rules to determine what the correct ordinal suffix would be based on the current map but I know that the original OP didn't want any more than one function. Either way this should help.

```
import random
import string
import sys

vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
consonants = [x for x in string.ascii_lowercase if x not in vowels]
SelectedWords = ['TRAILER', 'LAPTOP', 'SUNFLOWER', 'SKIPPING', 'AIRPLANE', 'HOUR', 'POTATO', 'HUGE', 'TINY', 'GOOD', 'BAD', 'YES', 'NO', 'WAGON', 'QUESTION', 'LAGOON', 'CAT', 'DUCK', 'GOANNA', 'POSTER', 'FUTURE', 'PRINCESS', 'RHYTHM', 'SUDDENLY', 'SNOW', 'MAGNET', 'TOWEL', 'RUNNING', 'SPEAKER', 'QUICKLY']
word_map = {x:{'consonants':len([y for y in x.lower() if y in consonants]), 'vowels':len([y for y in x.lower() if y in vowels]), 'letters':len(x)} for x in SelectedWords}
ordinal_map = {1:'st', 2:'nd', 3:'rd', 4:'th', 5:'th', 6:'th', 7:'th', 8:'th', 9:'th', 10:'th'}

def start_test(number_questions):
    current_question = 0
    correct_questions = 0
    if number_questions > len(SelectedWords):
        number_questions = len(SelectedWords)
    sample_questions = random.sample(SelectedWords, number_questions)
    print sample_questions
    print(' Test 1 START')
    print ('---------------------')
    for x in sample_questions:
        print ("Question {}/{}:".format(current_question+1,     number_questions))
        print ('---------------------')
        current_question += 1
        q_type = random.randint(1, 4)
        if q_type == 1:
            correct = word_map[x]['letters']
            ans = input('How many letters does "{}" contain?'.format(x))
        elif q_type == 2:
            correct = word_map[x]['vowels']
            ans = input('How many vowels does "{}" contain?'.format(x))
        elif q_type == 3:
            correct = word_map[x]['consonants']
            ans = input('How many consonants does "{}" contain?'.format(x))
        else:
            n = random.randint(1, len(x))
            correct = x[n-1]
            if sys.version.startswith('3'):
                ans = str(input('What is the {}{} letter of "{}"?'.format(n, ordinal_map[int(n)], x)))
            else:
                ans = str(raw_input('What is the {}{} letter of "{}"?'.format(n, ordinal_map[int(n)], x)))
        if str(ans).lower() == str(correct).lower():
            print('Well done correct! :)')
            correct_questions += 1
        else:
            print('Wrong :(')

    print ('You have completed your test!')
    print ("    Score {}/{}:".format(correct_questions , number_questions))
    try_again = input('Would you like to try again? (y/n)').lower()
    if try_again == 'y' or try_again == 'yes':
        start_test(number_questions)

start_test(9)
```